# post method in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby and i was following a tutorial for beginners, I've created a sign up form but the submit button seems like is not doing its work properly.

**registration_controller.rb:**

```
class RegistrationController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @account=Account.new
    end

    def create
        @account=Account.new(params_account)
        if @account.save
           redirect_to root_path ,notice:"Successfully created account"
        else
            flash[:alert]="something went wrong"
            render :new
        end
    end


    def params_account
        params.require(:account).permit(:mail ,:passwor ,:password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

**routes.rb:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 
  get "about" ,to:"about#index"

  get "sign_up" , to:"registration#new"
  post "sign_up" , to: "registration#create"
  
  get "/", to: "main#index"
end
```

**new.html.erb:**

```
<h1>Sign up</h1>
<%= form_with model: @account ,url:sign_up_path do |form| %>
<% if @account.errors.any? %>
 <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <% @account.errors.full_messages.each do |message|%>
       <div class="mb-4"><%= message %></div>
    <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
<%= form.label :Email  %>
<div class="mb-4">
    
    <%= form.text_field :mail ,class:"form_control" ,placeholder:"rahma@gmail.com"%>
</div>
<%= form.label :Password  %>
<div class="mb-4">
    <%= form.password_field :password ,class:"form_control" ,placeholder:"password"%>
</div>
<%= form.label :Confirme_password  %>
<div class="mb-4">
    <%= form.password_field :password_confirmation ,class:"form_control" ,placeholder:"confirme your password"%>
</div>
<div class="mb-4">
    <%= form.submit "Sign up",class:"btn btn-primary"%>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I looked in the terminal after i started the server and it shows:

```
Started POST "/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-03-15 19:21:48 +0100
Processing by RegistrationController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "account"=>{"mail"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 4)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 492)
```

and there is no error, and when I try to submit some data even when they are in the good format it raised an error:

```
Started POST "/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-03-15 19:37:56 +0100
Processing by RegistrationController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "account"=>{"mail"=>"ahmed@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Unpermitted parameter: :password. Context: { controller: RegistrationController, action: create, request: #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x00007f62d4bca258>, params: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "account"=>{"mail"=>"ahmed@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up", "controller"=>"registration", "action"=>"create"} }
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering registration/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered registration/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 11.6ms | Allocations: 1708)
  Rendered shared/_flash.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 19)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 24.9ms | Allocations: 4019)
Completed 200 OK in 34ms (Views: 28.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 5267)
```

I followed the tutorial step by step,everything works for him but not me, and I can't find the problem where.

Comment: Is it as simple as spelling password wrong?   Look at your code params.require(:account).permit(:mail ,:passwor ,:password_confirmation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Processing by RegistrationController#create as TURBO_STREAM
```

Your form request is processed with Turbo

You can disable this behavior by adding `data-turbo="false"` attribute:

```
<%= form_with model: @account, url: sign_up_path, data: { turbo: false } do |form| %>
```

Also you have typo in strong params (`:password` instead of `:passwor`), right version is

```
def params_account
  params.require(:account).permit(:mail, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```